# Changing the default behaviour of Windows 7 Explorer when renaming multiple files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, rename

I very frequently have to rename multiple files at once in explorer on Windows 7. When doing so explorer renames the "duplicates" with a number in brackets scheme - fine (well I'd prefer underscore...but fine)

But then I have to (re)re-name the first file as the plain name with no " (1)".

How can I avoid this situation? A registry hack would seem a likely candidate? (And a one-stop permanent solution) But I cannot find any information. Firing up a batch renamer each time would take even longer. I need something fast and easy.

In the graphic below you see five original files. I rename them to "test". Then the one I renamed is auto-changed to "test (1)" - Quite a liberty when you think about it. I renamed it test. I want it to be called test. The others can be called "test (n)" no problem. But I want that one to stay the same....

[image]

Comment: So it sound like you want the registry hack or whatever to change the default behavior of ***whichever version of Windows you are running*** where if you select multiple files and right click and select `Rename` on the group, that the file you are typing the new name in—since it only shows you renaming just one individual file out of the group you have selected during the rename operation—to keep that specific file's name as you type in the new name and not append the "(1)" and added spaces before the file name extension. You want to use Windows Explorer with a Windows Explorer solution only.

Comment: There are probably many 3rd party apps for this, native Windows scripted solutions for this, and maybe Windows Explorer alternative explorer app solutions for this which you do not want from how I understand your requirements.

Comment: @McDonald's - Yes that's exactly right, and I have edited the question to reflect I am looking for a Windows 7 solution - silly of me not to specify that!

Comment: On the assumption that there isn't a registry hack for this, how about an option in the right context menu which pops up a window for you to enter the new filename and then renames all the selected files using the rules you want?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a rename tool, such as [Advanced Renamer](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-9oDQx-3UAhVFKFAKHd1TBTsQFghJMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.advancedrenamer.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHsl66G3DGbILdx-FmKsIV4l5_6MA), [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-9oDQx-3UAhVFKFAKHd1TBTsQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bulkrenameutility.co.uk%2F&usg=AFQjCNFLmOPhUTlVXExYoro5EWZ24LhabA) or [Rename It](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-9oDQx-3UAhVFKFAKHd1TBTsQFgg3MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Frenameit%2F&usg=AFQjCNFzhoORbpN0X3nT3TeSmkCpwx2f2g)?

Comment: _"Firing up a batch renamer each time would take even longer"_ - I can do this with any third party system, at the moment I am using "dropit", but I am looking for a Windows change/registry hack that prevents this behaviour within explorer.

Comment: In ludicrous position of awarding the bounty to this answer, since there are no others, and at least this way I get a bronze badge "lol".

Comment: I was following this question since the bounty was offered. As ludicrous as it sounds, this really is the best answer for Windows 7. I've used Bulk Rename Utility (BRU) for years, and it is good. I have also struggled with the idea that *"Firing up a batch renamer each time would take even longer"* Make a shortcut named "bru" and drop it in your Windows directory. A simple `WINKEY`+`R` and you can run "bru". Quick and painless. With a little registry hacking, you could even add it to your right-click menu.