# Change the format when renaming multiple files?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, rename

In Windows 10/11 File Explorer is it possible to change the format when renaming multiple files?

When renaming multiple files, the result is something like this:
MyFile (1).jpg
MyFile (2).jpg
MyFile (3).jpg

I would prefer this:
MyFile-1.jpg
MyFile-2.jpg
MyFile-3.jpg

I am aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1222855/changing-the-default-behaviour-of-windows-7-explorer-when-renaming-multiple-file).
I do not have admin rights so I cannot install anything.

Comment: This is probably not possible within the GUI; you'd need to use CMD or (preferably) PowerShell. What have you tried, if anything?

Comment: Also, you probably can't change the _default_ behavior, only "manually" rename afterward.

Comment: Changing the defaults put me in mind of this old Internet joke, particularly point 2 regarding the defaults. https://www.dourish.com/goodies/see-figure-1.html

Comment: There is software that can do this, but its also not too hard to script with powershell or batch. Kind of depends on how often this is going to happen. If its just once, a powershell script or batch is probably the route to take. If it happens often, look for a batch rename program (google is your friend here)

Comment: I should add that I am unable to run powershell.

Comment: You're going to have to use a 3rd party application or a code/command interface of some sort: there is no way around this requirement. Considering this computer is not your own, while we COULD help find a set of commands you could use to do this, you really should be asking your IT support staff regarding this requirement. They will need to approve any software you download and run, or they will need to look at revisiting the PS blocking rule.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't have admin rights to install software, you could try a program that does not require admin rights.

I've used [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) for years and I like it.  Their main download is a full installer, but on their downloads page they also have a [portable version](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php#DownloadPortable) which requires no admin rights.

When you open it, it will have many different options which can accomplish what you want, but the "Replace" section would probably be easiest to start out with.  You can replace space-left parentheses with a hyphen, and replace right parens with nothing.

Comment: As OP does not own their computer, they will need to seek permission from their IT support staff before downloading and running software on their computer.

Comment: @music2myear is correct. When I execute this exe, I get the message "You must be logged in as an administrator when installing this program"

Comment: @AlLelopath portable versions do not install, so I think you're not following the instructions servererr0r gave quite right, but, you should talk to your IT folks about this before running it. They may (or may not) have strong policies and rules regarding running unapproved executables on computers they are responsible for, and you should not be risking your job trying to do this without their input.